# how to fix Typescript error in ionic 3? index.d.ts

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic3

[This is the error I'm having right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryiUn.png)

[image]

this is my package.json

{
"name": "Ambusis",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.10",
    "@ionic-native/browser-tab": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.5",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^7.6.2",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.9",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.2.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "pkg.json": "^2.0.7",
    "rxjs": "5.5.8",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.18",
    "typescript": "~3.1.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-browsertab": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

this is the code it is referring to

```
export type CustomEventName<T> = T extends EventNameString ? never : T;
```

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

P.S if I save a file, It will be fixed

thanks in advance guys!

**EDIT:**

[after following sir john's advice, only one error is now left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Ggm.png)

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code as text instead of an image. Edit your question to do so. Thank you

Comment: sir, I really don't know what code should I put here. because if I save a file then refresh the page, It will be fixed.

Comment: please include your `tsconfig.json` here

Comment: Sir, @JohnVelasquez I've put it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay add **skipLibCheck** so that it will skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts) on compilation.

should be like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added it in my post as EDIT in the bottom of my post sir.